# How to replace GeoQuerySet in Django model for Django 2.0+

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am trying to upgrade an old GeoDjango project to user newer versions of software, but I am getting an error when trying to upgrade Django from 1.7.5 to newer than 2.0. Apparently the GeoQuerySet was removed in 2.0. But I am not sure how I should remove it, and what to replace it with.

Here is a piece of my models.py with the relevant code.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from collections import OrderedDict

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

import clustering


class PropertySaleQuerySet(models.query.GeoQuerySet):
    """ QuerySet with additional clustering methods for the PropertySale objects """

    def _single_dot_serialize(self, p):
        return OrderedDict([
            ('id', p.uid),
            ('type', 'dot'),
            ('sale_type', p.sale_type),
            ('latitude', p.geometry.y),
            ('longitude', p.geometry.x),
        ])

    def _cluster_serialize(self, cluster, num):
        counts = {}
        centroid = cluster.centroid

        if len(cluster.items) < settings.CLUSTER_BREAK:
            return [self._single_dot_serialize(p) for p in cluster.items]

        for item in cluster.items:
            if item.sale_type not in counts:
                counts[item.sale_type] = 0
            counts[item.sale_type] += 1

        return [OrderedDict([
            ('id', num),
            ('type', 'cluster'),
            ('latitude', centroid[1]),
            ('longitude', centroid[0]),
            ('extent', cluster.extent),
            ('chartData', counts)
        ])]

    def cluster_saletype(self, bbox_string):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(float, bbox_string.split(','))

        dx = x2 - x1

        thresh = dx / settings.CLUSTER_THRESH_DENOM

        properties = list(self.filter(geometry__isnull=False).only('sale_type', 'geometry'))
        clusters = clustering.cluster(properties, threshold=thresh,
                                      getpoint=lambda p: (p.geometry.x, p.geometry.y))

        return sum((self._cluster_serialize(cluster, num) for num, cluster in enumerate(clusters)),
                   [])

    def list_map_points(self):
        points_list = (self.filter(geometry__isnull=False)
                       .only('uid', 'sale_type', 'geometry')[:settings.MAP_PAGE_PROPERTIES_LIMIT])
        return [self._single_dot_serialize(p) for p in points_list]


class PropertySale(models.Model):

    DETAIL_FIELDS = ('property_id', 'lawsuit_id',
                     'court_nbr', 'case_style',
                     'legal_desc_l', 'legal_desc_s',
                     'judgment_date', 'writ_nbr',
                     'sale_location', 'prop_type', 'class_code', 'school_district',
                     'address_full',
                     'struck_off_date', 'struck_off_amt', 'faq')


    HAS_PHOTO_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', True),
        ('N', False)
    )
    SALE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('SALE', 'Sales'),
        ('RESALE', 'Resales'),
        ('STRUCK OFF', 'Struck-off'),
        ('FUTURE SALE', 'Future sales')
    )

    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='othr_acct_info_id')

    sale_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    venue_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='venue_group_id')
    lawsuit_id = models.IntegerField()
    property_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ls_property_id')

    state = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    # db_column must be explicitly set so it can be looked up in QuerySet via
    # PropertySale._meta.get_field()
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, db_column='county')

    cause_nbr = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    court_nbr = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    precinct = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    case_style = models.CharField(max_length=2004)
    legal_desc_l = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True)
    legal_desc_s = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    judgment_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    sale_nbr = models.IntegerField()
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='sale_date_time')
    sale_date_only = models.DateField(db_column='sale_date_only')
    sale_location = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True)
    property_loc = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True)
    county_sale_list = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True)
    sale_published = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    sale_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SALE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_nbr = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

    prop_type = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    class_code = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    school_district = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, db_column='street_name')
    prop_address_one = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, db_column='phys_add_add1')
    prop_address_two = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, db_column='phys_add_add2')
    prop_city = models.CharField(max_length=24, null=True, db_column='phys_add_city')
    prop_state = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True, db_column='phys_add_state')
    prop_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, db_column='phys_add_zip')
    address_full = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True, db_column='phys_add_full')

    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    minimum_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    struck_off_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    struck_off_amt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=True)

    has_photo = models.CharField(db_column='lit_ps_display_photo',
                                 max_length=4000,
                                 choices=HAS_PHOTO_CHOICES)
    google_view = models.CharField(db_column='google_view_flag',
                   max_length=4000)
    image = models.BinaryField(null=True)

    book_nbr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    writ_nbr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sale_notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Generate these fields dynamically from the geometry column
    #latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6, db_column='latitude_dec')
    #longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, db_column='longitude_dec')
    geometry = models.PointField(db_column='geo_loc')

    objects = PropertySaleQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'property_sales_dmps'
```

Any help would be appreciated.